# opera driver is not working with Selenium - Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, opera, operadriver

I'm writing cross browser test script using Selenium web driver - Java. My firefox, chrome and IE browsers are opening and successfully running the script. But, in opera, only the browser is opening. Even `driver.manage().window().maximize();` also not working. Just open the browser and stay until I close it. When I close the browser manually, test suite fails.

Here is my java class.

```
package multiBrowser;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

public class MultiBrowserClass {

    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void multiBrowsers(String browserName) throws InterruptedException{

        if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){

            System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","D:\\My Work\\Setup\\JAR\\geckodriver.exe");
            ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();    
            FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);

        }
        if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\My Work\\Setup\\JAR\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")){

            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\My Work\\Setup\\JAR\\driver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }
        else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("opera")){

            System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "D:\\My Work\\Setup\\JAR\\driver\\operadriver.exe");
            driver = new OperaDriver(); 

        }

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.navigate().to("https://");

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='navbar-main']/ul/li[5]/a")).click();    
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='navbar-main']/ul/li[5]/ul/li/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("abc@mm.kk");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("1qaz2wsx");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='loginform']/div[8]/button")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Welcome abc@mm.kk")){
            System.out.println("User Successfully logged in");

        }else{
            System.out.println("Username or password you entered is incorrect");
        }

        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Here is the testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">

  <!-- firefox -->  

  <test name="FirefoxTestCases">  
      <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>  
      <classes> 
        <class name="multiBrowser.MultiBrowserClass"/> 
      </classes> 
  </test> 


  <!-- chrome -->  

  <test name="ChromeTestCases">  
      <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>  
      <classes> 
        <class name="multiBrowser.MultiBrowserClass"/> 
      </classes> 
  </test>


   <!-- internet explorer -->

  <test name="IETestCases">  
      <parameter name="browser" value="IE"/>  
      <classes> 
         <class name="multiBrowser.MultiBrowserClass"/> 
      </classes> 
  </test>

     <!-- Opera -->

  <test name="OperaTestCases">  
      <parameter name="browser" value="opera"/>  
      <classes> 
         <class name="multiBrowser.MultiBrowserClass"/> 
      </classes> 
  </test>

</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

I've downloaded operadriver from [this](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases) page (operadriver_win64.zip).

Here is how Opera browser is opening.

[image: Opera Browser]

Opera version is 41.0.2353.56.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: It is happening with the latest version of Opera. I have the same problem all the tests stopped working. Browser gets opened with data,; in the URL. nothing happens further.

Comment: So, what did you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\My Work\\Setup\\JAR\\driver\\operadriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Then installed opera 38. Problem solved. :)

Comment: Is it ChromeDriver() or OperaDriver()? I stopped running on Opera as I didn't want to downgrade. Can you stop Opera from updating to latest versions?

Comment: I don't have a method to test the latest opera version. sorry. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverManager.operadriver().setup();

WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.